# Vim: Use an expression as a filename

Tags: vim, scripting, editing

I'm doing some debugging, which involves checking logfiles name "blah N.log" where N is an integer.  Periodically, a new log file gets added, and I'd like to just skip to the next log file, rather than explicitly do `:e blah\ N.log`.  I can't just do `% vim *.log` and then `:n`, b/c not all the log files exist yet.

I've got an expression that yields the next logfile name:

```
:echo substitute(expand('%'), ' \zs\d\+', \=submatch(0) + 1', '')
```

But I can't figure out how to pass the result of that expression to an `:e` command.   Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's **a** way to do it - though I hope there's a more elegant way.

```
:execute ':e ' . substitute(substitute(expand('%'), ' \zs\d\+', \=submatch(0) + 1', ''), ' ', '\\ ', '')
```

I have to add a second `substitute()` command to escape the space in the filename.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can wrap it in a function. I would do the following:

```
function! GetNextLogfile()
    "" store expression in a
    "" let a=...
    return a
endfunction
```

then

:execute "edit " GetNextLogfile()

You might want a mapping or abbreviation.

Comment: +1 : I was hopeing for a one-liner, but this is a good method to note

Comment: If you plan to repeat this many times, maybe is worth to include some functionality in the vimrc... :)

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way: `:e <CTRL-R>=` brings up the expression prompt.  Enter the appropriate expression (including using up for expression history), and then hit `<Enter>` to substitute the value in the original prompt.

This makes the keystrokes:

```
:e <CTRL-R>=<Up><Enter><Enter>
```

Which is not as few as just `:<Up><Enter>` to redo my `:exec` command, but a useful trick, nonetheless.